# Add time to datetime and check in if statement

Tags: php, datetime

I am stuck. I have a database with colummn `datetime` in `comments` table. Basicly when user adds a new comment it's inserted in this table and the datetime is stored. So what i want to do now is to check if, lets say 1 minute is passed since he last commented. But i am getting all the time true in if statement.
Well. Before posted this did the last check. Output is not as expected.
My code.

```
$limits = new Limits();
$user = new User();
$time = new DateTime();

$time->add(new DateInterval('PT' . 1 . 'M'));
$stamp = $time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$limit = $limits->check_comment_limit($user->loggedInUser());

if($limit->time < $stamp){
echo 'Take a brake';
}
//for debugging
echo $stamp . '<br>';//2014-03-18 13:38:41
echo $limit->time; //2014-03-18 01:37:37
```

Ok obviusly `$limit->time` is smaler than `$stamp`. With `time()` it's simple, `time() + 60` but how to do this with datetime?

Comment: $stamp is a string. Don't you want to compare DateTime values or DateInterval values instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is that you want to do:

```
<?php
 date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); 

 // Get current datetime.
 $now = new DateTime("now");

 // Get last comment datetime.
 $comment = new DateTime('2014-03-18 13:26:00');

 // Get interval limit between comments.
 $limit = new DateInterval('PT1M');

 // Calculate the difference between the current and last commented datetime.
 $diff = $now->diff($comment);

 // Calculate the total minutes.
 $minutes = $diff->days * 24 * 60;
 $minutes += $diff->h * 60;
 $minutes += $diff->i;

 // Debug output
 echo $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').'<br>';
 echo $comment->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').'<br>';
 echo $limit->i.'<br>';
 echo $minutes.' minutes <br>';

 // Limit smaller than difference? Next comment is allowed.
 if($limit->i <= $minutes) {
    echo "Your comment has been saved!";
 } else {
echo "Your aren't allowed to comment now. Wait ".intval($limit->i*60 - 
      $diff->format('%s'))." seconds until you are allowed to comment again.";
 }
 ?>
```

**Edit: Added missing calculation of total minutes. Otherwise the calculation don't work with dates with the same minutes but other day or hour.**

**Another and much simpler/generic (working with every interval) solution would be like this:**

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); 

// Get current datetime.
$now = new DateTime("now");

// Get last comment datetime.
$comment = new DateTime('2014-03-18 16:45:00');

// Get and add interval limit to comments.
$limit = new DateInterval('PT1M');
$comment->add($limit);

// Debug output
echo $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').'<br>';
echo $comment->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').'<br>';

// Limit smaller than difference? Next comment is allowed.
if($comment <= $now) {
    echo "Your comment has been saved!";
} else {
    echo "Your aren't allowed to comment now. On ".$comment->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')." you 
            are allowed to comment again.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Added fix to the first solution and a second one.